# Get the full path of file read in directory

Tags: c#, tree, directory

I am  reading files from directory  and adding  it to the  tree.
I want  to know the each file's full path, and  get the  date  modified.
When i  use  GetFullPath it  gives me path like :  **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\old.mp4**
which is  not  actually  the path of  the  file.

```
    System.IO.FileInfo[] Files = directory.GetFiles();
    for (int FileCount = 0; FileCount < Files.Length; FileCount++)
    {          
        **lblTest.Text = lblTest.Text +"<br>"+ Path.GetFullPath(Files[FileCount].ToString());**                   
        DirNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(Files[FileCount].Name));             
    }
```

Can  anyone  help me  doing  this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FileInfo.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

> Gets the full path of the directory or file.

```
lblTest.Text += Files[FileCount].FullName;
```